# Linux kernel fault injection

Tags: linux-kernel

I am trying to inject fail page allocator on run_test by using Linux Fault injection framework. My command is running successfully but I am not getting that which type of error I will get after inject.
I have also configured my custom kernel according to the requirement of fault injection. When I run that

```
FAILCMD_TYPE=fail_page_alloc \ .
/tools/testing/fault-injection/failcmd.sh --times=100 \
-- make -C tools/testing/selftests/ run_tests
```

It runs but I don't know how to verify the result.
`/proc/sys/vm/oom_kill_allocation_task`
after this my that file change to 1 as a parameter inside it but before that it was 0 by default.